# Замена подстроки

Tags: javascript

Почему не работает данный код?

```
var sctrictname = "Генадий Степаныч";
var coolname = sctrictname.replace("адий Степаныч","ка Рыжий";
alert(coolname);
```

Comment: Конечно. потому что синтаксическая ошибка. В консоли, кстати, она написана

Comment: вот если бы из за этого то хорошо, но в коде скобочка закрыта, но всё равно не работает...Р.S. Пример исправил, спасибо

Comment: А зачем исправил в вопросе? Теперь всё работает. код рабочий теперь

Comment: Спасибо. Правда, буду внимательнее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Знаем, функцию replace не закрыли скобочкой.

```js
var sctrictname = "Генадий Степаныч";
var coolname = sctrictname.replace("адий Степаныч","ка Рыжий");
console.log(coolname);
```